# Website can only search or sort data from a database

Tags: c#, sql, razor

I've created a basic ecommerce website for college, I am having issues with sorting and searching my products table my page displays the products fine.
the website is made in visual studio 2012, using razor v2 markup with C#.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Store";
    var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
    string sql = "";

    switch (Request["sort"])
    {
        case "PriceASC":
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Products order by Product_Price ASC";
            break;
        case "PriceDESC":
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Products order by Product_Price DESC";
            break;
        default:
            sql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS ORDER BY Product_ID";
            break;
    }

    if (Request["search"] != "")
    {
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Products where Product_Keywords like '%" + Request["search"] + "%'";
    }
}
```

This is the code I'm using, independently they both work, but when i put them together like that, whichever one is second, takes over and breaks the first. I've swapped them over multiple times to test this, any ideas on how to get them to work together nicely?

Comment: What is the value of "Request["sort"]" when you step through it?

Comment: when you use the debugger.. what is the value of `switch (Request["sort"])` `Request["sort"]` is that a string or of type HttpRequest..? if so then change the ending to 
`switch (Request["sort"].ToString())`

Comment: I have no idea how to get the debuger to tell me that, but i tried to add .ToString() anyway, and it just gave a compiler error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" <a href="?sort=PriceASC">Price (Lowest to Highest)</a>    thats the link to trigger it, if thats what you mean

Comment: really.. you're executing `sql = "...."` **twice**. what'd you think will happen? magically two different queries in one variable will magically **combine** their effects? you need to write a query that will **have both WHERE and ORDERBY** to get find&sort.. not two queries with one of each clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason when you combine them it no longer works, is because you're overwriting the query you made in the first step.  What I would do is break that process up into parts.

```
//declare your variable.  I added a connection and command so I can include parameters in the process.
string orderBy = "";
string whereClause = "";
string sql = "";

//create your order by clause
switch (Request["sort"])
{
    case "PriceASC":
        orderBy = "order by Product_Price ASC";
        break;
    case "PriceDESC":
        orderBy = "order by Product_Price DESC";
        break;
    default:
        orderBy = "ORDER BY Product_ID";
        break;
}

//create your where clause.  
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["search"])) // forgot the ! here
{
    whereClause = string.Format(" where Product_Keywords like '%{0}%'", Request["search"]); // very unsafe to plug this in.  should use parameter

}

sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Products{0} {1}",whereClause, orderBy); //build your query string.  if no search parameter was given the where clause will be blank, but the order by will still exist.

@foreach (var row in db.Query(sql))
{
    //some code here
}
```

Comment: I've just tried that code, however it doesnt like SqlConnection() and SqlCommand().... says the type or namespace name couldnt be found for both of them also says that Request does not exist in the current context. this was based off example code from the lecturer, which is pretty much the same, except for field names and stuff, yet his works fine.

Comment: @Improwse:  I'd suggest reading carefully and understanding what changes David has introduced aroudn the `sql` string variable and apply the same to your working code

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't even see your database line at the top.  I was for some reason assuming you were using the System.Data.SqlClient namespace.  If you ignore the connection and command parts the query string building sections should word fine.

Comment: Yeah, that's gone way over my head ahaha, what i really dont get is how my lecturers code is virtually the same as mine, and runs fine.

Comment: I removed the parts about the command and connection to make it more clear. The only thing I can come up with for why the lecturer's code works is that it has to be slightly different.  Any chance that you could post his code so we can take a look?

Comment: ooh okay so this code workd, however when i call the sql command it cant find the variable "sql" obviously because you've removed it, so how would i get it to display the results, this is my calling code  @foreach (var row in db.Query(sql))

Comment: Thank you! no errors now, however it only sorts, doesn't search anymore

Comment: I found my typo.  It needed to be if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty()) instead of if (string.IsNullOrEmpty()).

Comment: Thank you! you have saved me and my course mates so much hassle, thanks for including comments so i can understand and learn form what you've done :)

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help